# python command line arguments in main, skip script name

Tags: python, for-loop, command-line-arguments, argv, sys

This is my script

```
def main(argv):
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        for x in sys.argv:
            build(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

so from the command line I write `python myscript.py commandlineargument`

I want it to skip `myscript.py` and simply run `commandlineargument` through `commandlineargument(n)`

so I understand that my for loop doesn't account for this, but how do I make it do that?

Comment: If the `main` function takes an `argv` parameter, it should probably _use_ that parameter, rather than ignoring it and using `sys.argv` instead…

Comment: Also, you don't need the `if` check at all. If there are no arguments, the loop will successfully run 0 times, so let it do so.

Comment: @abarnert I have an else

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is a list, you can use slicing `sys.argv[1:]`:

```
def main(argv):
    for x in argv[1:]:
        build(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

But, if you can only have one script parameter, just get it by index: `sys.argv[1]`. But, you should check if the length of `sys.argv` is more than 1 and throw an error if it doesn't, for example:

```
def main(argv):
    if len(argv) == 1:
        print "Not enough arguments"
        return
    else:
        build(argv[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is to learn about and use `argparse`, though.

Comment: I've used that before, what is the benefit between it and sys.argv or using optparse vs something else

Comment: It's the thing to use for arg parsing (unless you need `cliff`). It has a great API. It's not deprecated like `optparse`. It standardizes the look+feel of your script.